# targeting div in some other page

Tags: html, anchor

I have two pages say abc and xyz

in abc i have an anchor tag, and when i click on that it should go to some div in page xyz.

i used  in the page abc

and in xyz i put ... before that div..what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a `#` and the value of the `id` of the element you are targeting to the end of the URL:

```
http://example.com#id_value_of_target_element
```